# Django function for views takes too long

Tags: django, django-views

I'm currently using a Docker & Django setup. I have to fill a database with data from API requests. I was hoping to do this everytime you went on a certain page (pretty easy: just have your views.py call the function that fills the database and voila).
But the problem is, the function takes a long time, several minutes from within django (and about half the time with Spyder).
So I usually just get a TimeOut and the page never loads (I admit I have a lot of API requests being made).

I've read some stuff on using Celery but am not quite sure how it's supposed to work.

Anyone know how I could get around this to be able to load the database?

**Edit:** some code

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    fill_db()
    context = {}
    context['segment'] = 'index'
    html_template = loader.get_template( 'index.html' )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

fill_db function

```
def fill_db():
    fill_agencies()
    fill_companies()
    fill_contracts()
    fill_orders()
    fill_projects()
    fill_resources()
```

Example of a fill function:

```
r = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+EXTENSION,auth=(USER,PASS))
data0 = json.loads(r.text)
    
conn = sqlite3.connect('/app/database.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()
    
    
for client in data0['data']:
    BoondID = client['id']
    name = client['attributes']['name']
    expertiseArea = client['attributes']['expertiseArea']
    town = client['attributes']['town']
    country = client['attributes']['country']
    mainManager = client['relationships']['mainManager']['data']['id']
        
    values = (BoondID, name, expertiseArea, town, country, mainManager)
    c.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO COMPANIES (BoondID,name,expertiseArea,town,country,mainManager) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);", values)
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without seeing your code. But I guess that loading page for several minutes is not ok, are you inserting million of raws there? 
Please share your view and show what operations you do in order we can help.

Comment: Added some code as an edit. Some of the fill functions are a lot more complex (several API requests per item in data0['data']

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use celery to run long tasks?

Comment: I'm currently trying to use the python threading library, I'll see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I used python's threading library.
I defined

```
agencies_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_agencies, name="Database Updater")
```

and called `agencies_thread.start()` inside my views function.

This works fine.